# Managing international users

Tags: paypal

**There are three major problems with the collection of payments:**

Our company deals with Hungarian products, including the product description of accented characters are. The new RestAPI can successfully manage the payments to resolve the first round, but I can not accented characters to pass the paypal server.

If HTML.Encoding I'm using, the cipher text will be displayed on the checkout page does not decode the Paypal server. (Environment: Windows, .NET, C#)

So:

**1. How do I use accented characters with the name of items?**

***Update:***

I tried UTF8 as follows:

1.1. get the access token:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: charset=UTF-8" \
 -H "Accept-Language: hu_HU" \
 -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
 -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

1.2. answer:

```
{"scope":"openid https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card 

https://api.paypal.com/v1/developer/.*",
"access_token":"5tz416Qgym8Si9RM0nBS4DNSrGRFCMu5vZ923s--hLM",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"app_id":"APP-8KK24973T6066201W",
"expires_in":28800
}
```

1.3. The content json (I saved as UTF-8 text file with notepad with name 'content-utf8.json')

```
{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://example.com/your_redirect_url/",
    "cancel_url":"http://example.com/your_cancel_url/"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":**"Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógépes tanfolyam"**
    }
  ]
}
```

1.4. Send the payment

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer 5tz416Qgym8Si9RM0nBS4DNSrGRFCMu5vZ923s--hLM' \
--data 'content-utf8.json'
```

1.5. The answer

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1385f58
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1385f58) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.42.27.39...
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (23.42.27.39) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=CALIFORNIA; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=Partner Su
pport; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*        start date: 2013-08-20 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-08-21 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api.sandbox.paypal.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of
use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA
- G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
> Authorization:Bearer 5tz416Qgym8Si9RM0nBS4DNSrGRFCMu5vZ923s--hLM
> Content-Length: 12
>
* upload completely sent off: 12 out of 12 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< PayPal-Debug-Id: eb749926be259
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 200
< DC: origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com
< Date: Tue, 15 Oct 2013 09:03:52 GMT
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: DC=origin2-api.sandbox.paypal.com; secure
<
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST",
"message":"The request JSON is not well formed.",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
"debug_id":"eb749926be259"}
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

***The bottom line:***
**MALFORMED_REQUEST: The request JSON is not well formed.**

+++

We plan to our customers from different countries, so it would be nice if paying by PayPal page (if supported by the language) would be displayed in their language.

**2. How do I solve it as returned by Paypal approval_url page displayed in English/Hungarian (or any other language supported by paypal)?**

When paying customers redirected to the PayPal site where you can pay with credit card, you should fill in a few fields (firstname, lastname, address, phone, etc). Tulum would be nice if we could retrieve these fields forward data.

+++

**3. How do I get through the PayPal RestAPI (or otherwise) to send client data to the server before the PayPal payment?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Paypal accepts only UTF-8. I've not tried Hungarian languages, but UTF-8 will cover that. Make sure all your calls are encoded that way and they should go through.

Paypal will likely show them pages in the closest language to them. I don't see Hungarian explicitly listed in in the LOCALECODEs listed on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/). Sorry I can't be of more help here.

As to how to send data to Paypal, I find CURL works really well for this.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent at my support! I tested using curl, but failed. Either way, look for UTF8, if that helps.